# LARAVEL - where inside array have id and a value that greater than 80

Tags: arrays, laravel, eloquent, where-clause

hello all so i have a question,

i have a sql database that have object array inside it, it will be like this

| id_data | array | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `{"id":1032,"prc":77},{"id":1033,"prc":97}` | 2021-09-28 12:30:04 |
| 2 | `{"id":1032,"prc":85},{"id":1034,"prc":97}` | 2021-09-28 12:30:04 |
| 3 | `{"id":1030,"prc":85},{"id":1031,"prc":97}` | 2021-09-28 12:30:04 |
| 4 | `{"id":1032,"prc":90},{"id":1033,"prc":97},{"id":1035,"prc":97}` | 2021-09-28 12:30:04 |

and what i want to do is **take every data with id 1032 that has prc greater than 80 with its**

so in this table it would take **id number 2, and 4**

i need take the data using **eloquent laravel**, can somebody help me?, i'm still new to laravel

```
Data::where("something here")->get()
```

Comment: try Data::where('id',1032)->where('prc', '>' , 0 )->get();

Comment: no it can't be like that, the id and prc inside the column array @HuzaifaQidwai

Comment: You can't do like this as your column array could be type of string. So in my point of view it's not possible by using eloquent. To use  eloquent properly save this data in other table.

Comment: yah i have that idea too, but i didnt have any permission to do it in my project now

Answer (score 1):

Take a see to the answer of a question like yours ([How to query array inside JSON column in Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64860420/16706782)).

You can use `whereJsonContains` ([Laravel JSON queries](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses)).

> This feature is not supported by the SQLite database

```php
Data::whereJsonContains('array_field->id', '1032')->get();
```

**Updated**:

> @brian christian: how i can get the "prc greater than"

```php
...->where('array_field->prc','>', '80')
```

And mysql query is ([Mysql JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html)):

```sql
select * from tbl where
   json_contains(array_field, '{"id":1032}') and
   (select min(all_prc.prc) from json_table(array_field,'$[*]."prc"' columns(prc int path '$')) as all_prc) > 80
```

After all you can use Regex like this:

```sql
select * from tbl where
   `array_field` REGEXP '\\"id\\":\\s{0,}1032' and
   `array_field` REGEXP '\\"prc\\":\\s{0,}(8[1-9]|9\\d)|(\\d{3,})'
```

In eloquent:

```php
Data::whereRaw('`array_field` REGEXP \'\\"id\\":\\s{0,}1032\'')
    ->whereRaw('`array_field` REGEXP \'\\"prc\\":\\s{0,}(8[1-9]|9\\d)|([1-9]\\d{2,})\'')
    ->get();
```

`\\"id\\":\\s{0,}1032`: All rows that have id value 1032.

`\\"prc\\":\\s{0,}([8-9]\\d)|([1-9]\\d{2,})`: All rows that have prc greater than 80 (81-99) and (100-Infinite).

Comment: so, it literally we dont have to mantion column array ?

Comment: In your question's table you mentioned that column name is `array`, so i wrote `array->id`.

Comment: i see, i think it will work, i see this link to https://stackoverflow.com/a/64860420/16706782 that you give to me. now i search how i can get the "prc greater than"

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: i cant use that, i have to combine that the data have id 1032 and also in id 1032 have a prc more than 80,
this code literally give me the prc more than 80 but its no need to have the id 1032 on it.

what i want to achieve is like this 

        `Data::whereJsonContains('array', ['id' => 1032, 'prc' => 80])->get();`

but if i use this code it give exact match 80 not more than 80

Comment: You should write these methods together: `Data::whereJsonContains('array->id', '1032')->where('array->prc','>', '80')->get();`